# How to refresh viewpager after delete operation

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

In my app ,i used view pager to show my image gallery .

after deleteing any image from my gallery , view pager should get updated.

My Activity

```
public class FullScreenViewActivityForSelfImage extends Activity{

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private Utils utils;
private FullScreenImageAdapterForSelfImage adapter;
private static ViewPager viewPager;
DatabaseHelper db;
ArrayList<Image> aryimages;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen_view);
    db=new DatabaseHelper(this);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

     aryimages= db.getimages();

    Intent i = getIntent();
    int position = i.getIntExtra("position", 0);

    adapter = new FullScreenImageAdapterForSelfImage(FullScreenViewActivityForSelfImage.this,
            aryimages,this);

    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    // displaying selected image first
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
}
public static ViewPager getAdapter() {
    return viewPager;
}
}
```

My Adapter Class

```
public class FullScreenImageAdapterForSelfImage extends PagerAdapter 
{

    private Activity _activity;
    private ArrayList<Image> _imagePaths;
    ArrayList<Image> aryimages;
    public ImageListAdapter ImageListAdapter;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Context context; 
    int columnWidth,width,cellWidth,padding,height;
    DatabaseHelper db;
    int i;
    String  id,name;

    // constructor
    public FullScreenImageAdapterForSelfImage(Activity activity,
            ArrayList<Image> aryimages,Context context) {
        this._activity = activity;
        this._imagePaths = aryimages;
        this.context = context;
        db= new DatabaseHelper(_activity);
        Display display = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        width = size.x;
        height = size.y;

    }
```

My Adapter where delete service is called

```
btndel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext());
                alertDialog.setTitle("Confirm Delete...");
                alertDialog.setMessage("You are about to delete all images of this product continue");
                alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                                // Write your code here to execute after dialog

                                name = _imagePaths.get(position).Image_name.toString();


                                String imei=db.SelectImeiNo();
                                id=db.getidbyname(name);
                                System.out.println("selected imei = "+imei);
                                System.out.println("selected id = "+id);
                                dialog.cancel();



                                 WebServiceTask wst = new WebServiceTask(WebServiceTask.POST_TASK, context , "Deleting Image...");


                                 wst.execute(new String[] { Service_url });



                            }
                            });
```

In Adapter i tried to refresh

```
public void handleResponse(String response) {

    System.out.println("handle REsponse...got result..."+response);

    if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("0"))
    {
        System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!Server Busy try again latter!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
        Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "Server Busy try again latter", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    else if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("1"))
    {

        System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!!!Image deleted!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");

        Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "Image deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        db.deleteImageSelected(id);

        _imagePaths.remove(i);
        ImageListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }


  }
```

Image Adapter

```
public class ImageListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    //private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Image> Img;
    private LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    public ImageListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Image> Image) {

    //  this.context = context;
        this.Img = Image;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return Img.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.imageshow, null);
        } else {
            view = convertView;
        }

        ImageView iv= (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageshowView1);
        TextView name= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Imageshownametv);
        TextView id= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Imageshowidtv);
        TextView desc= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Imageshowimagedesc);

        id.setText(Img.get(position).Image_id);
        byte[] I= Img.get(position).image;
        System.out.println("Byte array of the image "+I);
        Bitmap bp=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(I, 0, I.length);

        iv.setImageBitmap(bp);

        return view;
    }

}
```

But it is not done

so please help me..

Comment: try call `this.notifyDataSetChanged();` after `ImageListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: What is `ImageListAdapter`? It is never being initialized. Or at least it is not in the part you posted.

Comment: ImageListAdapter is in same adapter class...see Updated post...

Comment: But where is it initialized?

Comment: Initialize  `public ImageListAdapter ImageListAdapter; in FullScreenImageAdapterForSelfImage constructor. Like ImageListAdapter new ImageListAdapter():`

Comment: You mean to say as...ImageListAdapter = new ImageListAdapter(context, _imagePaths);..??????

Comment: Nice it Refresh the pager , but it not removing deleted image....

Comment: @anupamaJ Need to remove image using selected ID and refresh ur adapter.

Comment: Fab!!!! its done like smooth......Please help me one more time...I wanted to do same with my image drawer....please help...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59843/discussion-between-piyush-gupta-and-anupamaj).